# DeferredResult Empty Body

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539755/response-body-is-empty-when-using-deferredresult), however I am having this issue now.

If I change my controller to return a `ResponseEntity<?>` the body comes through fine, but if it returns `DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>>` then I get my headers and status code but no response body.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use of `DeferredResult` is not simply a matter of changing the controller's response type. A controller which returns a `DeferredResult` will likely delegate handling of the request to a thread pool (or some async mechanism) and whatever actually performs the request must set the response on the `DeferredResult`. Something like this:

In the controller:

```
DeferredResult deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

// pass deferredResult into a runnable task (or something similar) 
// which is scheduled for execution via a thread pool (or something similar)

return deferredResult;
```

In the task which executes the request on behalf of the controller:

```
// do some work
// ...
deferredResult.setResponse(responseBody);
```

Comment: Yup, we have a callback which sets the body. I found we had a wierd filter stripping the response body further down the chain.